# Securing Rest Service Resources Using Apache Shiro

Tags: java, rest, shiro

I'm trying to secure my rest services written using dropwizard by Apache Shiro. First I initialized the security manager in the main method.

```
    Factory<SecurityManager> factory = new IniSecurityManagerFactory("classpath:shiro.ini");
    SecurityManager securityManager = factory.getInstance();
    SecurityUtils.setSecurityManager(securityManager);
```

Then I wrote a service for user login.

```
if (!currentUser.isAuthenticated()) {
        UsernamePasswordToken token = new UsernamePasswordToken(username, password);
        token.setRememberMe(true);
        try {
            currentUser.login(token);
            System.out.println("USER AUTHENTICATED!!!!!!!!");
        } catch (Exception uae) {
            System.out.println("Error logging in .................");
        }
    }
```

Then I declared a method with some java annotations.

```
    @RequiresAuthentication 
    @RequiresRoles("admin")
    @GET
    @Path("/account")
    @ApiOperation(value = "getAccount")
    public void getAccount() {
        //do something
    }
```

But when I accessed this resource without logging in, I was successful.

What mistake am I doing? Or should I add something more? Like in the web.xml?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found this repo very useful. https://github.com/silb/dropwizard-shiro/tree/release-0.2. I followed the instructions given in this. But there is one more thing I added in the configuration file.

```
@Valid
@JsonProperty("shiro-configuration")
public ShiroConfiguration shiro = new ShiroConfiguration();
```

Then in the resources class, I wrote login and logout as two services.

```
@POST
@Path("/session")
@Produces(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
public String login(@FormParam("username") String username, @FormParam("password") String password, @Auth Subject subject) {
    subject.login(new UsernamePasswordToken(username, password));
    return username;
}

@PUT
@Path("/logout")
@Produces(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
public String logout(@Auth Subject subject){
    subject.logout();
    return "Successfully logged out!";
}
```

And then I annotated the secured resources with @RequiresAuthentication annotation.