# Dropwizard-Shiro : Unauthorized Access Even After Logging in

Tags: java, dropwizard, shiro

I wrote some rest web services using dropwizard. Then I used [dropwizard-shiro bundle](https://github.com/silb/dropwizard-shiro/tree/release-0.2) to secure my resources, which I have described in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37701155/securing-rest-service-resources-using-apache-shiro) question. I've also used swagger UI to test my resources. Everything worked fine in the swagger UI. I wrote a php web application that consumes these services. There is a login page in the php application which calls my login service. The log in is successful but when trying to access some other resources through the php application, it gives Unauthorized Access error. Why am I getting this error? Is it because the created session expiring?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue: isAuthenticated() returns false, after I logged in and tried to access some other jax-rs Resources. In my scenario it is a ReactJS Client with AXIOS that does the request.

How I fixed it (it was the Frontend that was wrong):
I saw that I didn't do xmlhttprequest with AXIOS, because on ChromeConsole I could see that the cookie was not sent CROSS-ORIGIN to the server (HTTP-Header: set-cookie, cookie and so on)

Then I did it with $.ajax

```
xhrFields: {
  withCredentials: true
},
```

and everything is ok. Shiro draws the Jsessionid out of HTTP-only-cookie apparently. And there was no clear error message of why it was not working. Hope I can help you in some way :-)